# Type Script don't find local CSS module

Tags: css, typescript, types, module

I'm refactoring my React app to Type Script. In each component Type Script gives me this error

> Cannot find module './.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations

How I can resolve this error without webpack(if this possible)?

Comment: Typescript has no knowledge of CSS (or images, or HTML, or...). Anything that lets you "import" something other than Javascript or Typescript source files is doing some magic to make that happen (e.g. webpack). So no that is definitely not possible. Either use webpack, or just add your CSS to the page normally, or use some CSS-in-JS solution.

Comment: What about options in tsconfig.json?

Comment: No. At least not as of today in 2022.